# Catalog product flat reindex issue: errno: 121 Duplicate key on write or update (Magento 1.9.3.8)

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

When I try to reindex `catalog_product_flat` from command line I get following error.

`Reindex finished with error message "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table`magento_db`.`#sql-4f16_e84`(errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")". catalog_product_flat`

I tried to truncate all **catalog_product_flat** tables and rerun it, same result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_2;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_3;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_4;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_5;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_6;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;